# element.val() is not a function when i Try to validade a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to validate my inputs on the focusout() event, this way I can validate before the click on the submit button. but it throws me the error above[SOLVED].

Now the alert is showed infinitly, like if it had a loop.

Form:

```
<form id="formcontato">
                  <br>
                  <label> Nome:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                  <p class="palerta" id="valida_nome"></p>
                  <br>
                  <label>Email: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                  <p class="palerta" id="valida_email"></p>
                  <br>
                  <label>Telefone:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="00 0000-0000" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                  <p class="palerta" id="valida_telefone"></p>
                  <br />
                  <label>Mensagem:</label>
                  <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem" name="mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>
                  <p class="palerta" id="valida_mensagem"></p>
                  <br>
                  <div class="text-center">
                     <button type="submit" class="button"id="enviar">Enviar</button>
                  </div>
               </form>
```

JS:

```
function validate(element){
  if (element.val()===""){
    alert("is empty");
  }
  else{
    alert("It's ok");
  }
}
$("input").focusOut(function(){
   validate($(this))
});
```

Comment: you should use `$.each('input', function(i, v) {validate(v);});` - input is too ambigious

Comment: also make it a global function by doing: `$.fn.validate = function(element) {//code};`

Comment: There is no particular reason to do either of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is a jQuery function.  You were passing a raw DOM node to your validate function; instead you should send a jQuery object as shown below:

```js
function validate(element) {
  if (element.val() === "") {
    console.log("is empty");
  } else {
    console.log("It's ok");
  }
}
// Since you also have a textarea, I've added that to the items to be validated on focusout. IRL you would probably best use a classname to identify the fields to be validated:
$("input[type='text'],textarea").focusout(function() {
  validate($(this))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="formcontato">
  <label> Nome:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <p class="palerta" id="valida_nome"></p>
  <label>Email: </label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <p class="palerta" id="valida_email"></p>
  <label>Telefone:</label>
  <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="00 0000-0000" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  <p class="palerta" id="valida_telefone"></p>
  <label>Mensagem:</label>
  <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Deixe sua mensagem" name="mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>
  <p class="palerta" id="valida_mensagem"></p>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could send the raw DOM object and test its `.value` instead of `.val()`:

```js
function validate(element){
  if (element.value===""){
    console.log("is empty");
  }
  else{
    console.log("It's ok");
  }
}
$("input").focusout(function(){
   validate(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```

Note also that `focusOut()` is not a function; `focusout()` is correct.

#### Endless loops

After a long debugging session in chat, we tracked down the source of the endless-loop problem:  `alert()` temporarily blurs any currently-in-focus field. This led to a loop when tabbing from one field to another: field A's `focusout` fired simultaneously with field B receiving focus; `alert()` blurred field B, triggering its `focusout` event; voila, endless loop.

I changed the above examples to use `console.log` instead of `alert`, which does not trigger this behavior.

Comment: Yeeess, it works, BUT, it throws me "It's empty" like it is a loop when he should show only one time :/ I'm thing to put a counter, there's a better alternative?

Comment: There's no loop in the above code; whatever's causing that must be in code not included in your question.

Comment: I really tryed but It keeps showing me in loop, With your code it works, but in mine not and this function is the only that make reference to my Form... I have only 3 inputs..

Comment: Sorry, but I really have no way of knowing what's causing that problem without seeing the remainder of your code.   A wild guess: are you setting the .focusout event three times, once for each input?  If so, each time you're setting it you're setting it on all three inputs, so you'd wind up with three repetitions of the event on each input.

Comment: I've made one experiencie, inserted some value one the input, and, when I focusout, it throws me "Its ok", and after that he shows me "its empty again". is like he keeps executing the function... I will edit the question this my from code.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira I updated this answer to include the new HTML code added to your question to demonstrate that there's no looping behavior. There must be something else going on in your page to cause that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144382/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-daniel-beck).